# Populating a ListBox from row array

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone explain what's wrong with my code? I am trying to populate a ListBox on an array of rows. I get the run-time error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method, but it is unclear what I have coded wrong.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long

With Sheets("TempList")
    LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Sheets("tblSurveyMatches").ListBox1.RowSource = Sheets("TempList").Range("A2" & LastRow)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided this is an ActiveX control on your sheet, this will work, you need to use `ListFillRange` instead of `RowSource`.

```
Sheets("tblSurveyMatches").ListBox1.ListFillRange= Sheets("TempList").Name & "!" & Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Address
```

Note that it is normally *best practice* to qualify the `Range` to a worksheet, but in this case since all we need is an address string, it's not as important here.

Comment: It didn't seem to populate the listbox for some reason. Not sure why.

Comment: @Chris2015 look in the ListBox properties. What does it say in the ListFillRange after you run the code?

Comment: see my edited answer. Sorry, I posted the wrong code in. it is a real range, but not the right range!

Answer (score 0):

You have likely added a Forms control and not an ActiveX control to your sheet; form controls are addressed by the Sheets("tblSurveyMatches").Shapes collection.

The error is raised because there is no ListBox1 in Sheets("tblSurveyMatches") (there would indeed be if it was an ActiveX control).